# cocos2d create a circle shape and use it as a sprite

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, shapes, geometry, primitive

so I would like to create a circle shape with primitives on cocos2d and then use it as a sprite, How can I do it please ? 
I know that I have to use something like this :

`glLineWidth(16);
        glColor4ub(0, 255, 0, 255);
        drawCircle( ccp(s.width/2,  s.height/2), 100, 0, 10, NO);`

But it's hard for me to understand how it works and How to use it as a sprite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you really need CCSprite instance? you can create a subclass of CCNode, then in its

```
- (void) draw
```

method put your code there. your circle will have it's center position (0.f, 0.f)

```
@implementation MyScene

- (void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    CCNode* myNode = [MyNodeSubclass node];
    [node setPosition: someRandomPosition ];
    [self addChild: node];
}

@end

@implementation MyNodeSubclass

- (void) draw
{
    glColor4f(255, 255, 255, 255);
    CCPoint center = ccp(0.f, 0.f);
    CGFloat radius = 10.f;
    CGFloat angle = 0.f;
    NSInteger segments = 10;
    BOOL drawLineToCenter = YES;

    ccDrawCircle(center, radius, angle, segments, drawLineToCenter);    
}

@end
```

wrote this piece of code right here, didn't copy from xcode, but it should work as you want.     ccDrawCircle is a cocos2d function, declared in CCDrawingPrimitives.h

Comment: I know that but I want what is next :)

Comment: can you explain, why do you need CCSprite instance, not CCNode? maybe then I can try to help you to find the solution

Comment: I want CCNode, I know that I have to do - (void) draw but my problem is that I don't know what to put in this method and how to put the circle that has been created in my scene. sorry for my english I'm french :)

Comment: ohh... ok. if you want to do smth with your circle (for example, if it is the debug version of your game object, so you may want to move it, scale, rotate, etc.), create your own subclass of CCNode, in your subclass override draw method. in this method place your drawing code. For example, setup lines, color and drawing a circle in your case. then create an instance of your CCNode subclass and add it to your scene. You'll get all you had drawn in subclass's draw method at position of it's instance. And then you can do anything you want with this CCNode subclass instance(move, rotate, etc.)

Comment: Can I use a subclass of CCSprite instead of a CCNode ? or is it good for performance ?

Comment: No, it is not good for performance, but I prefer not to use classes with too many useless methods for my case as parent classes. If I need , for example, possibility to fade my object(i.e. to change it's opacity), i will implement CCRGBAProtocol, but not choose CCSprite as parent class. But you can feel free to do it, if you want.

Comment: Hey , it creates a polygon with ten side if segment is 10. If i give some large value , it comes close to the circle. Any way to get the circle straight.